# What are the most useful "defaults"?

Tags: mac-osx, mac, settings, defaults, preferences

Mac OS X has a commandline tool called "defaults". It lets you set certain properties, for example:

enable the "Debug" menu in Safari:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeDebugMenu 1
```

What is the most useful "hidden" "defaults write ..." command you have ever issued?

Answer (score 4):

There is a database of these hidden settings at [secrets.blacktree.com](http://secrets.blacktree.com/).  They also offer a free PrefPane you can install to twiddle these (instead of cutting and pasting from the website into Terminal).

Answer (score 3):

My favorites:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari TargetedClicksCreateTabs -bool TRUE
```

The above forces all links to open in new tabs, instead of new windows.

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location "/path/to/save/screenshots"
```

This one saves your screenshots somewhere else, other than your desktop.

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture type PDF
```

And this one changes the format of your screenshoots to PDF. I am sure some might find this one handy.

Answer (score 2):

```
defaults write com.apple.dock showhidden -bool YES
```

ghosts out the icons of apps that are currently hidden.

Well, actually, the most useful I *ever* wrote was, IIRC:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSInterfaceStyle NextStep
```

but that doesn't do anything on versions of OS X with Aqua :-(.

Comment: ah, NextStep, the sweet memories... :)

Comment: actually, that was Rhapsody - which by default used a Platinum interface style.

Answer (score 2):

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunes AppleDisplayScaleFactor .75
```

Shrink iTunes to 75% normal size. It's off-topic, and not really that useful (unless you're using a small display), but fun enough that I can't resist posting it. It works for other apps too, e.g. To shrink Calculator.app by 50%:

```
defaults write com.apple.Calculator AppleDisplayScaleFactor .5
```

Comment: how is this off-topic? i think it's awesome _and_ i didn't know it yet

Answer (score 2):

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

Disables the creation of .DS_Store files on Network Shares.